# How to make a worksheet function more efficient?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to make a worksheet function that loops through rows more efficient. Here is what I have -

```
Dim ws as worksheet, wks as worksheet, lastrow as long, i as long
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set wks = Sheets("Sheet2")

With ws
Lastrow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 to Lastrow
.Range("CS" & i) = Application.Vlookup(ws.Range("B" & i), wks.Range("B2:X100000"),23,false)
next
end with
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried VBA `find` function?

Comment: No, how does FInd work?

Comment: Does this code work?  If so, this question belongs on CodeReview

Comment: @Chrismas007 That's not a valid close reason. Vote to close because it's on-topic here, not because it may or may not be on-topic somewhere else.

Comment: @Mast Migration is a valid VTC reason.  It is in the VTC options.  However, CodeReview is not currently an actual option, so I had to make it a custom one.

Comment: @Chrismas007 actually ... you're wrong. But that's only because the VTC-Dialog's Design is incorrect in that regard. More info on that can be found in  [A Guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow Users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users), especially in the section "What you should not do."

Comment: @Chrismas007 Code Review doesn't accept migrations by said menu to eliminate a whole lot of false candidates. Please take a look at [this thread](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/311348/1014587), especially the answers.

Comment: @Mast TBH, I'll just VTC as Too Broad then in the future and STILL refer them to CR.  I see that in your and Vogel's links the main counter-point is that CR doesn't want these kinds of posts.  But as a community member of SO, my purpose is to get them off SO...

Comment: @Chrismas007 Your purpose is to close them. Don't migrate questions if they'll get closed on the other end, that's wasting a lot of people's time.

Comment: @Mast I'm not migrating.  I'm saying I think this should be closed on SO.  A moderator would have to migrate and only if 5 people voted in the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would remove all the reading and writing on cells from the loop:

```
Dim rg_table As Range, rg_lookup As Range, values(), r&

Set rg_table = [Sheet1].UsedRange
Set rg_lookup = [Sheet2!B2:X100000]

' load the values to search
values = rg_table.columns("B").Value

' lookup the values
For r = 2 To UBound(values)
  values(r, 1) = Application.VLookup(values(r, 1), rg_lookup, 23, False)
Next

' write the results to the sheet
rg_table.columns("CS") = values
```

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid iterating through the rows as much as possible. I would suggest that you instead do a paste of the Vlookup function in the range of the CS column.

Comment: Why the downvote? I'd be happy to know why someone disagrees why what I mentioned wouldn't be more efficient for the OP.

Answer (score 1):

This is how it would go if you used the `find` function:

```
Dim ws as worksheet, wks as worksheet, lastrow as long, i as long
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set wks = Sheets("Sheet2")

Lastrow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 to Lastrow
ws.Range("CS" & i) = wks.Range("B:B").find(ws.Range("B" & i).Text, , xlValues).Offset(0, 22).Value
Next i
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: I had misspelled the formula. Try now.

Comment: It ran ok this time, but no values were returned to my sheet1. Does wks. need to be added so that the formula is referencing Sheet2?

Comment: Now I'm getting. "Object variable or With block variable not set"

Comment: It runs through like 6 lines and then stops and gives me the error message.

Comment: Why don't you assign a variable to the result first and see what you get when you debug it? The code is working fine for me (use last edit).

Comment: Are some of your lookup values numbers?

Comment: it works for the 6 lines. all lookup values are numbers

Comment: No change. same 5 lines coming through

Comment: maybe because it's not finding on that value. maybe iferror resume next?

Comment: You get "Object variable or With block variable not set", right? Are you using the exact same code I wrote?

Comment: Yes, same code. It works when I add an On Error Resume next, but I should probably use some sort of IF statement instead.